# NLog: How to include static characters in an inner layout

Tags: c#, nlog

When using NLog to write to a file target, I want my layout to include " [xxx mS]" if event-properties:item=dur is non-null.  Otherwise, nothing will be appended.  How can I add the "[" and " mS]" to the when's inner text below?  Also, should I use something other than length() in the when's condition for non-null detection?

```
${message}${when:when='length(${event-properties:item=dur})'>0:inner=${event-properties:item=dur}"
```

If dur is 437, the log output would be...

```
<message> [437 mS]
```

If dur is not set, the log output would be...

```
<message>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
<nlog>
   <variables>
     <variable name="durationMs" value="${when::when='${event-properties:item=dur}'=='':else= \[${event-properties:dur} mS\]" />
     <variable name="defaultLayout" value="${message}${durationMs}" />
   </variables>
</nlog>
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit more trial-n-error led me to this solution...

```
${message}${when:when='${event-properties:item=dur}'!='':inner= [${event-properties:item=dur} mS]}
```

It seems you don't have to escape, or quote, the white space and/or square brackets in the 'inner' layout.  Whatever appears after 'inner=' is placed into the output.

Edit: Changed conditional (replaced length(...)>0) based on Rolf Kristensen comments.

Comment: Think this is faster `${when::when='${event-properties:item=dur}'=='':else= [${event-properties:dur} mS]`. The call to `length('')` has an extra overhead.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I wanted to know.  I have updated my answer (above).  I'll mark your suggestion as the answer though I used the format shown above in my code.